# How to Close programs using python on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, process

How do I close programs on mac using python?

I want something like this:

```
import os

process_name = "GoogleChrome"
os.system(f"end_process {process_name}")
```

Comment: try `killall Chrome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the osascript command with AppleScript to close or quit applications
try this

```
import os

def end_process(process_name):
    applescript = f'tell application "{process_name}" to quit'
    os.system(f"osascript -e '{applescript}'")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_name = "Google Chrome"
    end_process(process_name)
```

Comment: how do I get the process name? Is there a command that shows all process name? Because I'm not sure if that is google's process name.

Comment: if you want to know process name  using this  in powershell
"ps -ax -o comm"
This command displays a list of all running processes along with their names

Comment: Or in python
```
import os

def get_application_process_names():
    # Use the 'ps' command to get process names associated with terminal sessions
    ps_command = 'ps -cx -o comm'
    process_names = os.popen(ps_command).read().strip().split('\n')[1:]

    return process_names

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application_process_names = get_application_process_names()

    print("Running application process names:")
    for process_name in application_process_names:
        print(process_name)
```